# Are softwares like maya, autocad, 3d max, nuke, etc. helpful in anyway to a ui/ux designer

Tags: 3ds-max, user-experience, maya, autocad

Are the above softwares actually helpful in any practical way while applying for a job in big companies as a ui/ux designer?

Answer (score 2):

The good jobs usually hire you based on your design skills--not any particular software you may (or may not) know. As for the programs you listed, they won't hurt, of course, but they're pretty much relegated to 3D modeling tasks. If the company specializes in 3D UI work, maybe it'd be helpful, but for the most part, they're not typical tools of the UI/UX trade.

In fact, the bigger the company, the odds are the more pedestrian the software options will be. (For UI/UX work, that means mostly Adobe and Microsoft suites.)